# Entering multiple things in to one array in java

Tags: java, arrays

I am quite new to java but have a project i need to complete and am stuck on a certain part.

I want to allow the user to enter a route including, start destination, an end destination, and a number of stops. I have been able to do this, but then i want the user to have the ability of being able to add the same things again, to the same array. without deleting the existing route

here is the code i have so far

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;


public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        menu();
    }

    public static void menu(){
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("enter 1 to input a new route");
        int option = scanner.nextInt();
        if(option==1){
            inputRoute();
        }

    }

    public static void inputRoute(){
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);


        System.out.println("Please Enter Starting Destination");
        String startDest = scanner.next();

        System.out.println("Please Enter End Destination");
        String endDest = scanner.next();

        System.out.println("Please Enter Number of stops");
        int numberOfStops = scanner.nextInt();
        String[] stops = new String[numberOfStops];

        for(int i = 1; i<=numberOfStops; i++){

            System.out.println("Enter Stop" + i);
            stops[i-1] = scanner.next();

        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(stops));
        menu();

    }
}
```

however when this runs, if i go back and enter in another route, it will just delete the existing route.
Is there any way of appending the next route to the end of that array or any way of doing this?

thank you

Comment: Declare `stops` at the class level, instead of local to the function. You'll also need to resize the array, or use some type of dynamically sized collection.

Comment: There are a few ways you could handle that. You could declare it at the class level and initialize it to null. Then, when you read the size, you could check if it is null. If it is null, you could assign it a new array of the desired size. If it is not null, you could resize it to the current size + the incoming size.

Answer (score 1):

Like crush said. Rather than use a normal array of strings, use an `ArrayList<String>` object. Or even an `ArrayList<String[]>` and stash each individual route in there.

Comment: Please don't give full code answers to someone working on something so simple that it's obviously a school homework problem--don't make SO a "We'll do your homework for you" site.

Comment: Sorry, that's one of the things that really bother me--can't say just why. I'll change my down to un up just becasue you're so cool. :) (Had to edit the answer (no change) so I could re-vote)

Comment: I like to provide functioning code, but you're right; I should've had a more keen eye that the asker of the question has a rep of 1 and therefore is a brand-spanking new user (i.e. a fresh hotmail account for a student trying to get the community to do his homework)

Answer (score 1):

First of all you will need to declare the stops array as an instance variable, otherwise you will always be creating a new array whenever you call the method inputRoute().

and then to preserve old entries i can think of two ways-->
--> modify the loop as below...

```
for(int i = 1; i<=numberOfStops; i++){
        System.out.println("Enter Stop" + i);
        if(stops!=null)    //without the if condition it will also append null in the start
            stops[i-1]=stops[i-1]+", "+ scanner.next();   // you can you any separator 
        else
            stops[i-1]=scanner.next();
}
```

--> or you can ArrayList or any other Collection that provides auto increment

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring stops as a global variable. (right below the class line)

Also I would recommend using an ArrayList, List something on those lines

Answer (score 0):

You can't use an array for this (without constantly re-allocating them) as Arrays are fixed in size once created.

Use an `ArrayList` though and you can add as many items as you like whenever you like.

Comment: ArrayList just abstracts the re-allocations. It's still constantly re-allocating them as needed. I'm sure you know that, but your answer might be misleading to someone who doesn't.

Comment: @crush You are right, but are overstating the case. It doesn't constantly re-allocate them, it only re-allocates them when they grow so large and it does so by doubling the size. This means that even large collections need few iterations to get to the required capacity.

Comment: Right. He could do the same thing without an ArrayList. ArrayList just hides the details. I just didn't want him to get the impression that an ArrayList somehow magically doesn't need to reallocate.

Answer (score 0):

The easy (and slightly wrong) solution would be to make your array a static array that is defined outside any method.  That will get you going (although you will have to make the array big enought.

Other recommendations:

1. Capatilize your Main class--avoids confusiong (even moreso if you
   don't call it main!)
2. Make your public static void main method do
   this: new Main()
3. Then get rid of all the other statics.
4. Use a collection instead of an array.
5. instead of adding each entry into the array separately (which will make EVERYTHING harder for you), create a second class with 3 fields (start, end, stop) and each time you input another record, "new" an instance of the second class, place the three things into the new instance and place that instance on your collection.

It may seem arbitrary and unnecessary right at this minute, but if you have ANY follow-on work to do on this class these things will make your life easier.  If any seems confusing or you want to understand why, feel free to ask in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you.

Main file.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        menu();
    }

    public static void menu(){
        List<Route> routeList = new ArrayList<Route>();
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("enter 1 to input a new route");
        int option = scanner.nextInt();
        if(option==1){
            routeList.add(inputRoute());
        }

        System.out.println("Complete list of routes is "+routeList);

    }

    public static Route inputRoute(){
        Route route = new Route();
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter the name of the route");
        String name = scanner.next();
        route.setName(name);

        System.out.println("Please Enter Starting Destination");
        String startDest = scanner.next();
        route.setStartLocation(startDest);

        System.out.println("Please Enter End Destination");
        String endDest = scanner.next();
        route.setEndLocation(endDest);

        System.out.println("Please Enter Number of stops");
        int numberOfStops = scanner.nextInt();

        if(numberOfStops > 0){
            route.setStopList(new ArrayList<String>());
        for(int i = 1; i<=numberOfStops; i++){

            System.out.println("Enter Stop" + i);
            route.getStopList().add(scanner.next());
            }

        System.out.println("current entered route is "+route);
        menu();
        }
        return route;
    }
}
```

Route file:

```
import java.util.List;
public class Route {
    String name ;
    String startLocation;
    String endLocation;
    List<String> stopList;

    public Route() {
    }

    public Route(String name, String startLocation, String endLocation, List<String> stopList) {
        this.name = name;
        this.startLocation = startLocation;
        this.endLocation = endLocation;
        this.stopList = stopList;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getStartLocation() {
        return startLocation;
    }

    public void setStartLocation(String startLocation) {
        this.startLocation = startLocation;
    }

    public String getEndLocation() {
        return endLocation;
    }

    public void setEndLocation(String endLocation) {
        this.endLocation = endLocation;
    }

    public List<String> getStopList() {
        return stopList;
    }

    public void setStopList(List<String> stopList) {
        this.stopList = stopList;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        Route route = (Route) o;

        if (endLocation != null ? !endLocation.equals(route.endLocation) : route.endLocation != null) return false;
        if (name != null ? !name.equals(route.name) : route.name != null) return false;
        if (startLocation != null ? !startLocation.equals(route.startLocation) : route.startLocation != null)
            return false;
        if (stopList != null ? !stopList.equals(route.stopList) : route.stopList != null) return false;

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = name != null ? name.hashCode() : 0;
        result = 31 * result + (startLocation != null ? startLocation.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (endLocation != null ? endLocation.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (stopList != null ? stopList.hashCode() : 0);
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Route{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", startLocation='" + startLocation + '\'' +
                ", endLocation='" + endLocation + '\'' +
                ", stopList=" + stopList +
                '}';
    }
}
```